# "No value associated with key CodingKeys" Error when trying to get data from API - Swift

Tags: swift, cs50

Hi I am trying to make a pokedex app and I have previously in my code used the same API and was successful but now when I call a different link from the API I am getting this error:

```
keyNotFound(CodingKeys(stringValue: "root", intValue: nil), Swift.DecodingError.Context(codingPath: [], debugDescription: "No value associated with key CodingKeys(stringValue: \"root\", intValue: nil) (\"root\").", underlyingError: nil))
```

I am trying to get a description for the pokemon.
This is my current code that isn't working:

```
func loadFlavor() {
    guard let url = URL(string: "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon-species/1/") else {
        return
    }
    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { (data, response, error) in
        guard let data = data else {
            return
            }
        
        do {
            let result = try JSONDecoder().decode(SpeciesResults.self, from: data)
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                for typeEntry in result.root
                {
                    self.descriptionText.text = typeEntry.flavor_text_entries.flavor_text
                }
            }
        }
        catch let error {
            print(error)
        }
    }.resume()
}
```

And these are my structs:

```
struct SpeciesResults: Codable {
    let root: [PokemonFlavorResults]
}
struct PokemonFlavorResults: Codable {
    let flavor_text_entries: Zerodic
}
struct Zerodic: Codable {
    let flavor_text: String
}
```

Comment: You don't need SpeciesResults. Change `let flavor_text_entries: Zerodic` to ...`[Zerodic]` and then `try JSONDecoder().decode(PokemonFlavorResults.self, from: data)`. You'll need to change your for loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Issue:**

1. You don't need `SpeciesResults` model because `flavor_text_entries` object is already at the root level.
2. Use camel-case for defining your variables. In `Codable` you can use `convertFromSnakeCase` as the `decoder's` `keyDecodingStrategy`.

**Solution:**

So, the `Codable` models must be,

```
struct PokemonFlavorResults: Codable {
    let flavorTextEntries: [Zerodic]
}
struct Zerodic: Codable {
    let flavorText: String
}
```

And parse the *JSON* `data` like so,

```
do {
    let decoder = JSONDecoder()
    decoder.keyDecodingStrategy = .convertFromSnakeCase
    let results = try decoder.decode(PokemonFlavorResults.self, from: data)
    //use results here...
} catch {
    print(error)
}
```